# Web3 1.0 Nested contract promises

Tags: web3js, nodejs

What is the best way to handled nested contract call with web3 1.0? I'm trying to collect all data needed and format it into something useable. It could require 2 or 3 calls though. Is there a easy way to handle it, to know when all async calls have finished?

```
this.contract.methods.getPlayerAnimals(this.address)
.call({ from: this.address })
.then((animals) => {
  for (var animal of animals) {
    this.contract.methods.getAnimal(animal)
    .call({ from: this.address })
    .then((animalContract) => {
      this.playerAnimals.push(fullAnimal)
    });
  }
  this.socket.emit('playerAnimals', this.playerAnimals)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var animals = await this.contract.methods.getPlayerAnimals(this.address)
  .call({ from: this.address })
for (var animal of animals) {
  var animalContract = await this.contract.methods.getAnimal(animal)
    .call({ from: this.address })
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Assuming we are inside async function
this.socket.emit (
  'playerAnimals',
  await Promise.all (
    (await this.contract.methods.getPlayerAnimals (this.address).
      call ({ from: this.address })).
      map (animal =>
        this.contract.methods.getAnimal (animal).
          call ({ from: this.address }))));
```